# Excel VBA code: system error (the server threw an exception)

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes

I am somewhat new to VBA coding.  I have an excel file in which I have a list of users to whom an email is automatically sent requesting their validation through ticking the relevant checkbox.

I have managed to get the below code which is working fine. Lately, however, the code has begun to generate the following error message for no apparent reasons 'System error &H80010105 (-2147417851)': The server threw an exception.

```
Sub SendEmailUsingCOM()

'This macro will open an email session with Lotus Notes,
'add text from the sheet "email" to the body of the email,
'give the email a name and place an email adress.

 'Set up the objects requiered for automation into lotus notes
  Dim Maildb As Object 'The mail database
  Dim UserName As String 'The current users notes name
  Dim MailDbName As String 'The current users notes mail database name
  Dim AttachME As Object 'the attachment richtextfile object
  Dim vToList     As Variant, vCCList As Variant, vBody As Variant
  Dim MailDoc As Object 'the mail document itself
  Dim Session As Object 'The notes session
  Dim EmbedObj As Object 'The embedded object attachment)

  'Open and locate current lotus Notes user
   Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")

   UserName = Session.UserName
   MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"

  Set Maildb = Session.GetDatabase("", MailDbName) 'already open for mail
  If Maildb.IsOpen = True Then
  Else
  Maildb.OpenMail
  End If
  'Set up the new mail document
   Set MailDoc = Maildb.CreateDocument
   vToList = Application.Transpose(Range("S1").Resize(Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value)
   vCCList = Application.Transpose(Range("B1").Resize(Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value)
   MailDoc.Form = "Memo"

   MailDoc.Subject = "Demande de Validation"
   MailDoc.Body = [F1].Value
   MailDoc.SavemessageOnSend = True
   MailDoc.PostedDate = Now() 'Gets the mail to appear in the sent items folder
   On Error GoTo errorhandler1
   MailDoc.Send 0, vToList

   MsgBox ("Les validations ont été demandées")

   Set MailDoc = Nothing
   Set Maildb = Nothing
   Set Session = Nothing
   Set AttachME = Nothing
   Set EmbedObj1 = Nothing

   errorhandler1:

   Set MailDoc = Nothing
   Set Maildb = Nothing
   Set Session = Nothing
   Set AttachME = Nothing
   Set EmbedObj1 = Nothing

  End Sub
```

Many users have different excel spreadsheets with the same script and this error only occurs to one one of them. Also, if any other user tries to send an email (again, ticking any checkbox with the name of the validator in order to send an email to this person), no error message pops up. Could you please help me out with this error?

Many thanks.

Miguel

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: If you write `MsgBox MailDbName` before the line `Set Maildb = Session.GetDatabase("", MailDbName)` what do you get? Does it make sense?

Comment: I had a similar issue and I found it to be related to how fast I sent the mails. When I put a two second delay (or something - don't remember) between the calls it did not fail.

Comment: Thank you both for your time! Everything appears to be fine because I am able to run the code properly and successfully send the email, but my colleague cannot using the same code. It appears to be on the email session at the very beginning.. when I place the mouse pointer over 'Set Session = CreateObject ("Notes.NotesSession")' gives me value 'session = nothing'. By the way, we both have our IBM lotus notes opened